# JSON to a JSON array Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: json, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm using `Json.Net` to DeserializeObject Json data into object/collection (list)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I have tried this:

```
List<LanguageObject> lang = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LanguageObject>>(jsonData);
```

and tried this:

```
LanguageObject.Results lang = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LanguageObject.Results>(jsonData);
```

**I'm getting this error:**

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LanguageObject]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.   
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'meta', line 1, position 8.
```

**here my Json:**

```
{"meta":
{
    "status":200,
    "message":[],
    "resultSet":
          {"id":"05"},
    "pagination":     
     {
        "count":2,
        "pageNum":1,
        "pageSize":2,
        "totalPages":1,
        "sort":"ordinal",
        "order":"Asc",
        "currentUri":null,
        "nextUri":null
      }
    },
    "results":   
     {
         "id":0,
         "name":
         "Language",
         "DName":null,
         "qvalue":"language",
         "language":null,
         "mUsageCount":null,
         "Ordinal":0,
      "items":
         [
           {
             "id":0,
             "name":"English",
             "DName":"English",
             "qvalue":null,
             "language":null,
             "mUsageCount":null,
             "Ordinal":0,
             "items":[]
           },
           {
             "id":0,
              "name":"Spanish",
              "DName":"Spanish;",
              "qvalue":null,
              "language":null,
              "mUsageCount":null,
              "Ordinal":0,"
              items":[]
           }
         ]
     }}
```

**LanguageObject.cs**

```
   Public class LanguageObject
    {
    public class ResultSet
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pagination
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public int pageNum { get; set; }
        public int pageSize { get; set; }
        public int totalPages { get; set; }
        public string sort { get; set; }
        public string order { get; set; }
        public object currentUri { get; set; }
        public object nextUri { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        public int status { get; set; }
        public List<object> message { get; set; }
        public ResultSet resultSet { get; set; }
        public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string DName { get; set; }
        public object qvalue { get; set; }
        public object language { get; set; }
        public object mUsageCount { get; set; }
        public int Ordinal { get; set; }
        public List<object> items { get; set; }
        public List<object> __invalid_name__
                      items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Results
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object DName { get; set; }
        public string qvalue { get; set; }
        public object language { get; set; }
        public object mUsageCount { get; set; }
        public int Ordinal { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
        public Results results { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a `LanguageObject` class defined in your question.  I do see a `RootObject` class, however.  From what you have posted, you need to deserialize like this:

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);
```

Then you can get the `Results` from the `RootObject`:

```
Results lang = root.Results;
```

Comment: LanguageObject.cs is my class I have updated my question however I will give it a shot and post my results.